# .htaccess redirect works on OSX local but not Windows XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I created a .htaccess file to control access to a REST api while in development on an OSX machine running a local server. However, the actual host machine that i need to deploy too is a windows machine running XAMPP. I took the same .htaccess file and moved it from the development server to the live server and it seems to not function properly anymore.

Here is the .htaccess file contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess file is located the same directory as the api.php file which is a single directory in. So when I access this page hosted from the OSX machine, it is located at:

`<IP Address>/RESTDevelopement/api.php`

(The actual folder path on the machine is: `.../Documents/RESTDevelopment/api.php`)

When I go to the URL: `<IP Address>/RESTDevelopement/api/v1/query/` it responds by sending the request to `<IP Address>/RESTDevelopement/api.php?request=query/`

This works fine and I have been using it for several weeks without issue.

However, not so with the windows machine...

On my windows machine I have the XAMPP server running and I stored my project within the *htdocs* folder. The actual location is:

`G:\xampp\htdocs\RESTDevelopment\api.php`

I access it the same way as with the OSX:

`<IP Address>/RESTDevelopement/api.php`

However, when I go to the same page to use the api `<IP Address>/RESTDevelopement/api/v1/query/`it gives me an internal server error.

The log file says that it is in a redirect loop. I tried to follow the loop using the but it doesn't make much sense to me:

```
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.925963 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c81030/initial] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] add path info postfix: G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/api -> G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/api/v1/query/
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.925963 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c81030/initial] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] strip per-dir prefix: G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/api/v1/query/ -> api/v1/query/
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.925963 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c81030/initial] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] applying pattern 'api/v1/(.*)$' to uri 'api/v1/query/'
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.925963 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c81030/initial] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] rewrite 'api/v1/query/' -> 'api/v1/api.php?request=query/'
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.925963 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c81030/initial] split uri=api/v1/api.php?request=query/ -> uri=api/v1/api.php, args=request=query/
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.925963 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c81030/initial] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] add per-dir prefix: api/v1/api.php -> G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/api/v1/api.php
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.925963 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c81030/initial] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] strip document_root prefix: G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/api/v1/api.php -> /RESTDevelopment/api/v1/api.php
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.925963 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c81030/initial] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] internal redirect with /RESTDevelopment/api/v1/api.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.926963 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c8b018/initial/redir#1] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] add path info postfix: G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/api -> G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/api/v1/api.php
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.926963 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c8b018/initial/redir#1] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] strip per-dir prefix: G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/api/v1/api.php -> api/v1/api.php
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.926963 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c8b018/initial/redir#1] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] applying pattern 'api/v1/(.*)$' to uri 'api/v1/api.php'
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.926963 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c8b018/initial/redir#1] [perdir G:/xampp/htdocs/RESTDevelopment/] rewrite 'api/v1/api.php' -> 'api/v1/api.php?request=api.php'
[Tue Jan 05 11:41:15.926963 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6680:tid 1704] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.1.10.70:54696] 10.1.10.70 - - [10.1.10.70/sid#604b00][rid#2c8b018/initial/redir#1] split uri=api/v1/api.php?request=api.php -> uri=api/v1/api.php, args=request=api.php&request=query/
```

The last 5 lines are repeated several times in the log before giving the redirect error.

Things I have tried:

1. I made sure the htaccess file was being read by using a very simple test
2. I made sure the mod_rewrite module was working properly with a very simple test
3. I tried setting `RewriteBase` to various directories/folders in an attempt to determine whether it was being redirected wrong... I don't know much about this, so I was shooting blind and it didn't work.
4. I searched google for quite some time to see if anyone else had this issue with XAMPP but everyone seems to be using consistent patterns.

Note: I do have `AllowOverride All` set for this directory.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `api/v1/` is not the real path then use this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: wow you are right.... now why would this work on the OSX site by not on the XAMPP site? That's very strange....

Comment: Not sure but may be this option MultiViews was enabled there